# programatically adding a calendar event on iPad

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have a button on my iPad, on clicking it, an entry on the calendar should be created with a specific title and default time duration of 30min. How can I do that ? I have reached a point where I have inheritted the calendar object and also able to read it also.

**Question**: How do I add the entry to it from the code ?

Comment: fixed tagging. xcode irrelevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I pasted this from my code... post a comment if you have any confusion

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title     = @"EVENT TITLE";
event.notes     = @"Event notes here";
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];

[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Comment: Saurabh, here the event you are creating for an hour rite? How are u specifying the title of the event ?

Comment: set a string value in "event.title"

Comment: what is the need of the section and row variables here ? Sorry to annoy with these silly questions. I am new to this and getting a hand of it now

Comment: I edited the code to simplify the things.. Please review and post in comment if you have more confusion..

Comment: Saurab, one more clarrification here. Facing few more issues, in NSString *eventDateStr decalration what is ClubArr ??

Comment: Saurabh, can this be done such a user gets a pop up to select for duration in multiples of 15 like 15,30,45,60 only ? Is there a way such that I can provide these options and then make a entry?