# Kal calendar not fetching data from iPhone calendar

Tags: objective-c, ios, github, calendar, ekevent

I am trying to work with the Kal calendar. I got a copy from github. You can find it over [here](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal). Now when I test the nativeCal demo project on the simulator. It shows events on the calendar.

My guess is that they come from the calendar in the simulator. But when I test it on a real device it is not fetching any data (events).

Anybody worked with this github project before and can help me?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have same problem but actually this is not a problem but this is the sample events to show in the simulator. To see the events in the device you need add event manually in the code then you will find the event in the device.

Check this link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272186/programatically-adding-a-calendar-event-on-ipad) to add the event programatically.

i hope you can understand this

THanks